# Handle two dispatcher Servlets using AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to configure spring maven multimodule project. I have `two` dispatcher Servlets (say Foo {Module A}, Bar {Module B}) in two child **web** modules. All I am Trying to do is to configure everything single `root context` and say it is in Module A and with spring `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` I am configuring like

```
AppContext extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{
@Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { ... };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { Foo.class, Bar.class* }; //Bar.class Desired but not getting
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

Now the problem is when I am importing `module B` inside `module A`, Since both are war files and I am not able to access `Bar.class`. `Module A` is `Web application with UI` and `Module B` is `REST API`.

So, Is there any way to configure both inside single `application Context`, or do I need to create another application Context for REST module ?

If you need any information let me, know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use maven multi module functionality.

Add Below code in your pom.xml of **Module A**

```
<modules>
    <module>**artifactId of module B**</module>     
</modules>
```

Comment: This is what I did. But since `module A` is **war** file so other `Servlet Configuration` It is not visible in `Module B`

Comment: You have to import ModuleB in ModuleA. I assume that Your moduleB generate jar file.

Comment: actually `module b` is a `war` sadly